# (VB.NET) Round to 2 decimals globally?

Tags: vb.net, global, rounding

How can I make all the numbers that come up be rounded to 2 decimal places? What should I write in class level so that I don't have to write Math.Round(var, 2) a hundred times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can’t control this on the class level, nor should you.

You *should* control it where ever you output the numbers. But of course you don’t need to (and shouldn’t) repeat code over and over again: you can just make all output code call the same function.

Furthermore, you should *not* use `Math.Round`, and especially not in every computation (that will yield wrong results!). Instead, use `String.Format` to get the correct textual representation of your numbers, where you output them:

```
Shared Function Representation(number As Double) As String
    Return number.ToString("#.##")
End Function
```